# SQL Like Query in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oledbcommand

I'm wondering if anyone is able to shed light on why this won't work for me.  I am trying to run a standard sql query in my ASP MVC application and mostly this is fine.  But for some reason when I try to use the 'like' predicate with wildcards it doesn't return any results, it's as if it is using the ? parameter as a value instead of populating with the search value.  For example :-

This query returns results without the wildcard included.

```
    SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS L INNER JOIN ITEMDETAILS IT ON IT.LOCNUMBER = L.LOCNUMBER WHERE L.CLIENTNUMBER = ? AND IT.[DESC] LIKE ?;
```

This query doesn't return any results when I add the wildcard around the parameter value, but no idea why?

```
    SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS L INNER JOIN ITEMDETAILS IT ON IT.LOCNUMBER = L.LOCNUMBER WHERE L.CLIENTNUMBER = ? AND IT.[DESC] LIKE '%?%';
```

Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: Do any of the `IT.[DESC]` values actually have a question mark in them? That's what you're asking in that query.

Comment: Thanks Ragerory, That's what I thought was happening, so how do I use a wildcard on a parameter ?

Comment: I think you need to reword your question with some example of the data and your code (in addition to the SQL you have above), so that we can properly understand the issue, now that we've gotten this bit of confusion out of the way.